# NodeJS substituir janela terminal do windows

Tags: node.js, monodevelop

Me lembro que instalei o *NodeJS* em uma máquina windows e a janela terminal (Prompt de comando) foi substituía por uma janela *fullscreen*. Se não me engano tinha uma opção durante a instalação.

Instalei recentemente o *NodeJS v4.6.0* e não vi esta opção.

É possível esta substituição?

Comment: O node js é só um executável de linha de comando, ele não substitui o terminal. Provavelmente vc está confundindo com um editor no estilo vim ou vi.

Comment: Ele não substitui o terminal, apenas tem aquele executável onde vc pode executar os códigos .Independende disso é possível fazê-lo no próprio terminal do Windows.

Comment: O Github instala o git-shell. Será isso que procuras. De qualquer maneira ficas sempre com dois, o terminal do windows e o do github.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, amigo. Você provavelmente está confundindo. O node.js não instala nenhum novo terminal em nenhum Sistema Operacional. O que pode ter acontecido é você ter seguido um tutorial que lhe orientou a instalar o [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). 
Mas lembre-se que é altamente recomendado que você aprenda e execute o node.js em um ambiente Unix-Like.

E sim é possível substituir o terminal do Windows (prompt command) por outros como o [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

Answer (score -1):

Instale o VS Code. Por ele você terá seu ambiente de desenvolvimento e ativa o terminal sem ter de usar o cmd do windows.